# how to invoke html control event without html control

Tags: javascript, jquery, htmlcontrols

Is it possible to invoke fileupload event at button click?

I need something like this

```
  <input type="button" onclick="return buttonClicked()">
```

And invoking fileupload event should come inside buttonClicked() event

```
 function buttonClicked()
     {
       preventDefault();
       ...File upload event
     }
```

I have been searching for this functionality for some time and it seems quite a simple functionality but couldn't find any solution for this.

really need help on this one

Comment: Are you just trying to trigger an event, or do you want to actually  upload a file?

Comment: @Mathletics triggering an event is the first step. Of course I need to upload file(s)

Answer (score 0):

You may use following jQuery Plugin:

jQuery site link:
https://plugins.jquery.com/uploadfile/

Github link:
https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file

The pluging exposes following events as callback:

```js
$("#aDivforUpload").uploadFile({
    url: "http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload/upload.php",
    multiple: true,
    fileName: "myfile",
    onSubmit: function(files) {
        $("#eventsmessage").html($("#eventsmessage").html() + "<br/>Submitting:" + JSON.stringify(files));
    },
    onSuccess: function(files, data, xhr) {
        $("#eventsmessage").html($("#eventsmessage").html() + "<br/>Success for: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    afterUploadAll: function() {
        $("#eventsmessage").html($("#eventsmessage").html() + "<br/>All files are uploaded");

    },
    onError: function(files, status, errMsg) {
        $("#eventsmessage").html($("#eventsmessage").html() + "<br/>Error for: " + JSON.stringify(files));
    }
});
```

Here is the demo with nice documentation for this plugin:

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

**UPDATE :**
Here is the jsFiddle i've created:http://jsfiddle.net/raishul/2x32tq3p/

Comment: is this the url where the files will be uploaded?: http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload/upload.php

Comment: What server side language you are using? You can point it to your file handler server side page. Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Working with asp.net you can use **generic handler** and call it through ajax to upload your files.

if you are interested in this let me know to give you a complete answer.

In asp.net
You can use [this Tutorial](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/02/uploading-file-using-jquery-with-generic-handler-ashx-in-asp-net.html) one it's pretty much what I do. This will allow you to upload the file without post back. There is another way that uploads in the server side using asp.net control FileUpload, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: sure give me full answer

Comment: @Alex The Answer is Updated with a Link.